# How can I make graphs with boxed text or math and arrows?

Tags: plot, graphs

How can I make graphs like this?[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you considered using TikZ?

Comment: @CharlesB.Cameron thanks, will have a try :)

Comment: If this is a one-shot graph and you don't want to learn TikZ, you could just create the graphics separately in something like Inkscape or Ipe and include it using \includegraphics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this by using TikZ, here is the code:

```tex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, bm, listings, enumitem, geometry, titlesec,
array, makecell, caption, graphicx, float, algorithm, algpseudocode}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows.meta}

\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1.3cm, 
text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>={Stealth[scale=1.1]}]

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (agent) [process, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=2cm,
            label={[anchor=north,inner sep=5pt]north:Agent}]{};
        \node (pi) [process, left of=agent, minimum width=1cm, 
            minimum height=1cm,xshift=1cm, yshift=-0.3cm] {\(\pi\)};
        \node (env) [process, minimum height=1.5cm, below of=pi, yshift=-1cm] 
            {Environment};

        \draw [arrow] (env.163) -- ++(-1.5,0) node[anchor=south, xshift=0.8cm]
            {\(S_{t+1}\)} coordinate(a1);
        \draw [arrow] (a1) -- ++(-0.7,0) |- node[anchor=south, xshift=1.3cm] 
            {\(S_t\)} (pi);
        \draw [arrow] (env.197) -- ++(-1.5,0) node[anchor=south, xshift=0.8cm]
            {\(R_{t+1}\)} coordinate(a2);
        \draw [arrow] (a2) -- ++(-1.3,0) -- ++(0,3.2) 
            -- node[anchor=south, xshift=0.5cm] {\(R_t\)} (agent.154);
        \draw [arrow] (pi) -- ++(2.7,0) node[anchor=south, xshift=-0.8cm] 
            {\(A_t\)} |- (env);
        \draw [dashed,thick] (-2.7,-1.5) -- (-2.7, -3.2);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{center}

\end{document}
```